# Identity in the 9 lectures in random graphs

Tags: probability, graph-theory

In the 9 lecures in random graphs on pages 16/17

http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~chassain/GDT/documents/SpencerStFlour.pdf

they say let $n_{0}(k)$ be the minimum $n$ for which $\binom{n}{k} 2^{-\binom{k}{2}} \geq 1$. Then it says that for any $\lambda \in (-\infty,\infty)$ let $n=n_{0}(k)\left[1+\frac{\lambda+o(1)}{k}\right]$ it then follows that $\binom{n}{k}=\left[1+\frac{\lambda+o(1)}{k}\right]^{k}=e^{\lambda}+o(1).$

I am completely unsure as to how they arrived at the last part. Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot a factor $2^{-k(k-1)/2}$.

Comment: Ahh yes you are right, thank you so much for your help! My last question is regarding what they wrote at the start of the section. They said let $2^{-\binom{k}{2}}\binom{n}{k} \rightarrow c$ as $n,k \rightarrow \infty$. How does this fit in with what we have now given that $e^{\lambda}+o(1)$ is now not a constant?

Comment: ?? $e^\lambda+o(1)\to e^\lambda$, which is a constant, no?

Comment: I assumed as $n \rightarrow \infty$ it meant $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: No, $\lambda$ is fixed (but $k\to\infty$ hence $n_0(k)\to\infty$ and $n\to\infty$).

Comment: Ahh that makes much more sense!! Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

$$2^{-k(k-1)/2}\cdot{n\choose k}=2^{-k(k-1)/2}\cdot{n_0(k)\choose k}\cdot\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}\cdot\frac{(n_0(k)-k)!}{n_0(k)!}\sim1\cdot\left(\frac{n}{n_0(k)}\right)^k
$$